# How to make Menubar visible in full screen but hide in full screen video?

Tags: google-chrome, menu-bar, fullscreen

New to Mac, got 14" MacBook Pro 2021 (with notch). macOS 12.5.

Want to have Menu bar visible in fullscreen mode (so that notch screenspace would be in use rather than just left out black) BUT at the same time I want menubar gone in fullscreen YouTube videos (for a more immersive experience). I use Chrome.

Is there a setting allowing for that?

Thank you!

Comment: How about [maximizing the window](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/work-with-app-windows-mchlp2469/12.0/mac/12.0#mchlp7b91593) when you want full screen with menu bar?

Comment: That's not the same as full screen tho, is it?

Comment: It's similar. I'm suggesting an alternative solution to your issue. Tried it?

Comment: I did, but that's not quite what I was looking for. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Maybe after a couple of years we will get fix for this from Apple?

Answer (score 0):

i'm looking to solve the same issue. I'm looking for UNIX commands to show and hide the bar and perhaps tying it to bettertouchtool. i dunno. I'll let you know if I figure something out.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//apple.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.